# About a simple system of equations slightly changed

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, systems-of-equations

Well maybe it's a weird question but let me propose it :

Let the system :

$$ax+by-c=0,ux+vy-d=0$$

This pair of equations is easy to solve but now what happends if :

$$ax+by-c\simeq0,ux+vy-d\simeq0$$

I think we can use the probability as intuition but I find nothing on the web and I'm really curious to know it .

What the tools to approach this kind of equations ?

Comment: How is this different from linear regression (where we shift the inexactness onto $c$ and $d$)?

Comment: Add a third equation in $(x,y)$ to face  linear regression

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hum well I don't know what is a linear regression...Have you a pedagogic link ?

Comment: Are you serious or just kidding the old man ?

Comment: Euh no dear Claude ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici In fact I propose this question because I was thinking about the game Mikado and again I'm not kidding you. See https://www.academia.edu/48855374/Buffon_type_Problems_with_multiple_intersections_for_regular_lattices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to avoid the preliminary statistical considerations, let us discard the word *"linear regression"*.

Consider that you have $n$ equations
$$f_i=a_i\,x+b_i\,y-c_i$$ where the $(a_i,b_i,c_i)$ are known.

Consider the norm
$$\Phi(x,y)=\frac 12\sum_{i=1}^n w_i\,f_i^2$$ where the $w_i$ are weights you could want to assign to each equation.

Compute the partial derivatives
$$\frac{\partial \Phi(x,y)}{\partial x}=x \sum_{i=1}^n w_i a_i^2+y\sum_{i=1}^n w_i a_ib_i-\sum_{i=1}^n w_i a_i c_i$$
$$\frac{\partial \Phi(x,y)}{\partial y}=x \sum_{i=1}^n w_i a_i b_i+y\sum_{i=1}^n w_i b_i^2-\sum_{i=1}^n w_i b_i c_i$$

Since you look for the minimum of the norm to obtain the most probable values of $(x,y)$, set these partial derivatives equal to zero. So, two linear equations for two variables $(x,y)$. That is all.

Concerning the weights, I personally enjoy $w_i=\frac 1 {c_i^2}$

Comment: Thanks Claude !Is there any physical aspect in what you wrote ?Think Mikado :-)

Comment: @ErikSatie I think that we need a discussion in private. Do you agree ? If you do, let us see if we use a chat room, e-mail or phone.